# My Category extension is not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have added a category extension to my NSString class.   The method basically formats the string a certain way.  I have:

```
- (NSString *)formatStringAsColor {
    NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%@ color", self)];
    return formattedString;
}
```

Then I try calling this method elsewhere in my app but it says it cannot be found.

I try something like:
`NSString *string = [myOtherString formatStringAsColor];`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you importing the correct header files everywhere?

Comment: Did you import the category in this other class where you want to call this function? If you want your category to be globally included, add it to the prefix header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors in that code. Fixes below:

```
- (NSString*) formatStringAsColor {
                                                           v                 v
    NSString* formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ color", self];
           v
    return formattedString;
}
```

Should work better now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including in your header file of EVERY file you want to use it in:

```
#import "NSString+[nameOfExtension].h"
```

So, if your name of your extension/category file is NSString+Color then replace [nameOfExtension] with Color.